# Why is "science" in "Bachelor of Science" singular, whereas "arts" in "Bachelor of Arts" is plural?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, proper-nouns

In the following degrees — ["Bachelor of Science"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Science) and ["Master of Science"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Science) — "science" is an uncountable or singular noun.

In contrast, in ["Bachelor of Art**s**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Arts) and [Master of Art**s**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Arts), "art**s**" is countable and plural. Wikipedia says the Master of Art**s** "degree is usually contrasted with the Master of Science." If so, then they should probably use the same grammar, no?

From Cambridge dictionary,

> **arts** C1 [ plural ]: subjects, such as history, languages, and literature, that are not scientific subjects

There are several different majors/fields under each degree. We can have "Master of Science in Physics, Chemistry, Psychology, etc." and "Master of Art**s** in Linguistics, Political Science, Economics, etc." The point I am trying to make is that since the degrees are similar in the sense that they have multiple fields, shouldn't they both have the same noun form in the titles? Like, either both should have the countable or plural "arts" and "sciences", or both should have the uncountable "art" and "science".

There are departments/schools/programs with "science**s**" in their name though: Natural Sciences, Earth Sciences, etc.

Why do they not have the same noun form in the degree titles? Why is it not "Master of Science**s**"?

Comment: Note that the uncountable _science_ seems to contain all _sciences_ within it, but _art_ is usually used to mean "visual arts", which is much narrower that _the arts_. _Art_ can be used in a wider sense, but tends not to be. Having said this, the terms are originally Latin, but show the same difference: _doctor scientiae_ (singular) vs _baccalaureus artium_ (plural), and I don't know if the Latin word _ars_ was used in parallel ways in singular and plural or not.

Comment: Great question! To further complicate things, people do say [**art and science**](https://deyoung.famsf.org/calacademy/artscience): [_Why Art And Science Are More Closely Related Than You Think_](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/03/16/why-art-and-science-are-more-closely-related-than-you-think). We have colleges of **arts and sciences**: [1](https://artsci.washington.edu/) [2](https://as.virginia.edu/) [3](https://as.cornell.edu/) [4](https://www.usfca.edu/arts-sciences). But there's also [colleges of **arts and science**](https://cas.nyu.edu/)

Comment: You can get a Bachelor of Arts in chemistry and a Bachelor of Science in English.  The distinction is not the major but whether the degree requires working knowledge of a foreign language.

Comment: @Mary You mean B.S. degrees have no requirement for foreign language courses? I don't think that applies to every school, or even most schools I am familiar with.

Comment: *Science* is a relatively new word, with a history different from what some may assume. [Another recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254569) has some relation to this one, and may be of interest.

Comment: @epl Really varies from school to school. [This liberal art college](https://www.williams.edu/academics/areas-of-study/) has dispensed with their foreign language requirement, while [this one keeps it](https://www.swarthmore.edu/modern-languages-literatures/language-requirement). A lot of schools still have similar requirements and I don't think they are going away in spades in the foreseeable future.

Comment: The University of Cambridge still (I believe) gives only BA as the first degree, whatever the subject.

Comment: @ColinFine almost. Undergraduate Engineering gets you an MEng, and Medicine an MB and BChir.

Comment: @OrangeDog undergraduate engineering at Cambridge gets you both a BA and an MEng, so the first (most junior) degree is still BA.

Comment: To expand a bit on Colin Fine's comment: I also think the explanation is historical. Medieval universities taught seven subjects or "arts" comprising the trivium and the quadrivium. Having studied these, you'd get a *baccalaureus/magister artium* degree – since you studied several subjects, it makes sense for the designation to be in the plural. The notion of (natural) science as a unified whole, on the other hand, is much more modern. I don't know when the first *scientiae* degree was conferred, but I suspect that by the time it was, it made perfect sense for it to be in the singular.

Comment: Sounds like another "math" vs. "maths" debate...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Overview

**The central issue of question is the countable and uncountable usages of  the words *science* and *art***.

## Explanation

Following are two common **usages of *science***:

- (uncountable): **All activity that we think of as scientific** (that is, all research based on the scientific method).
- (countable): **Any field of science** (that is, any specific discipline of scientific research).

We might think about applying the same pattern as above to the word  *art*.
Between usages of the two words, *science* and *art*, we find great similarity, but also a few differences.

*Art*  is an activity, but it is one  that produces objects.

Any of the following are common ways to refer to **objects produced by artistic activity** (such as drawings, paintings, or sculptures):

- ***Art*** (uncountable)
- ***Artwork*** (uncountable)
- ***Works of art*** (countable)

Not all kinds of artistic activity produce artwork.

- ***The visual arts* are artistic activity that produces artwork**, and include drawing, painting, and sculpting.  (A *visual art* is any such field.)
- **The visual arts are contrasted  to  *the performing arts***, which include music, dance, and theater. (A *performing art* is any such field.)

In some cases, we  find that the word *art* confuses the activity with the objects.

As an example, the following two simple  statements  are not parallel:

- "I like science": From this statement, we understand that someone likes *to study science*.
- "I like art": From this statement, we think about *admiring artwork*, and lose the idea of studying. This loss gives us a reason to find a way to explain that someone likes to study art.

We need a way to refer to the activity of art, as distinct from artwork.
***The arts* are all activity that we think of as artistic.**

As *the arts* is a countable usage, we also have the singular form. **An *art* is any field within the arts, or sometimes, any field within only the visual arts**.

Putting together the above, following are common **usages of *art***:

- (uncountable): **One or more objects of art**, the same meaning as *artwork*.
- (uncountable): **All activity within the visual arts** (not including performing arts).
- (countable): **Any field within the visual arts** (not including performing arts).
- (uncountable): **All activity  within the arts** (including performing arts).
- (countable): **Any field within the arts** (including performing arts).

Since *science* is all activity that we think of as scientific, we have no strong reason to use  the term *the sciences*.
Yet, sometimes we want to emphasize the diversity and number of different fields, or to create a feeling that is general but also grand.

***The sciences* has the same meaning as *science***, but has a specific feeling that makes it  uncommon except in certain literary contexts.

We can conclude with the following:

- *Science* is the common way to express *all activity that we think of as scientific*.
- *The arts* is the common way to express *all activity that we think of as artistic*.

## Examples

For degrees, like a Bachelor's degree, we emphasize the activities, *science* and *the arts*. We call the degrees  *Bachelor of Science* and *Bachelor of Arts*. In titles, we often omit articles, otherwise we would use *Master of the Arts*. *Master of Sciences* would feel too general, as though someone had studied every field of science for a long time.

This patterns appears elsewhere.

Following are two examples, both related to the US government:

- The *[National Science Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Science_Foundation)*  and the *[National Endowment for the Arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Endowment_for_the_Arts)*   are both   agencies of the government. (The NSF might have been called the *National Foundation for the Sciences*, but this name may seem to emphasize the fields and their differences, rather than all of science together as a valuable pursuit.)
- The [Constitution](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States_of_America) lists the powers of Congress.

  It describes one of the powers in the following text
  ([Article I, Section  8, Clause 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Clause)):

  > To promote the Progress of Science and useful Arts, by securing for limited Times to Authors and Inventors the exclusive Right to their respective Writings and Discoveries;

  (Note that capitalization rules are different today than during the earlier period, which treated important common nouns the same as names and other proper nouns.)

  The text means that Congress has the power to pass laws related to intellectual property ("securing", "exclusive right"), specifically for copyright ("the arts", "authors", "writings") and for patents ("science", "inventors", "discoveries").

Comment: Honestly, I did not find the first version difficult to read at all. I would rather prefer that one vs the new edit, because this one is now longer.

Comment: _The sciences has the same meaning as science_ - I have to disagree with this.  _The sciences_ is the set of specific subjects, whereas _science_ is a much more general term.

Comment: I'd prefer "artifacts" to "objects" (to differentiate it from *direct/indirect object*) but YMMV.

Comment: Careful, I think there are two meanings of the word "art" that are getting lumped together: 1) the so-called "fine arts", e.g. music, painting, dance, etc; 2) "liberal arts" which includes some "soft" sciences (e.g. psychology) as well. I'm not an expert, but it seems that the terms "art" and "science" are not so distinct as we may think (at least in higher education, which seems like the point of the OP). The intertwined history (i.e. Greco-Roman) of the two likely influences how we see them today.

Comment: @user7761803: Would you expand by clarifying exactly what you believe is the difference?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I prefer to consider a more familiar word, such as *item*, compared to *artifact*.

Comment: @Kelvin: The representation of usages of *art* and derived terms is not an exhaustive list, and I doubt that trying to include one would support the main flow of ideas.

Comment: I upvoted, I liked the answer, I only suggested substituting "object" with "artifact" thinking that you would agree but if you don't that's perfectly fine. You don't have to please everyone all the time.

Comment: Re: "Works of art (countable)": Incidentally, this is sometimes called a *[singulative](https://glossary.sil.org/term/singulative)*. Other examples include *snowflake*, *grain of sand*, *piece of furniture*, *piece of fruit*, etc.

Answer (score 25):

The short answer is that the words "art/arts" and "science/sciences" are used differently in various idiomatic ways.

Both "art" and "science" can be considered *mass nouns*, often referred to as *uncountable nouns*. If you had a collection of many pieces of art, you could refer to it all as "my art". Likewise, "science" can refer to *all* science collectively, for example, "the advance of modern science", or "the laws of science".

Both can also be used in the plural when referring to individual *disciplines* or *types* of art and science.

- "The arts" refers collectively to all forms of art, including visual arts, literature, performing arts, culinary arts, etc. In the case of 'Bachelor of Arts' this extends to humanities and sciences.
- "The sciences" refers collectively to all forms of science, including biology, physics, chemistry, etc.

However, whereas the singular "science" is always an umbrella term that incorporates all disciplines of science, the singular "art" is nearly always assumed by default to refer to *visual art*, in particular, *painting and drawing*. If someone said "I'm a scientist", most people would follow up with "what kind?", whereas if someone said "I'm an artist" there would likely be an assumption that they produced paintings or drawings, and not that they were a performing artist. Usually, one would specify "I'm a musician" or "I'm an actor".

It seems logical then that the titles "Bachelor of Arts" and "Bachelor of Science" are so.

Comment: A nitpick: yes, ‘the arts’ *could*, conceivably, refer to culinary arts, but in most contexts it won’t (same goes for literature, although to a lesser extent by a great degree). Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Just a few fine points: 1) *Art* may refer to a single piece of artwork as well as a collection. 2) The assumption may be too restrictive that *art*  is "nearly always assumed" to refer to visual art, though I do agree that in a plain vernacular context the sense of the word generally points in favor of visual arts.

Comment: Maybe virtual arts is a bit too narrow (I'd also think of performing artists), but I agree, it doesn't have the all-encompassing quality as science has. When people say "I am an artists" I wouldn't think of them as a writer, for example. But literature is an art and a BA in literature is a BA of Arts.

Comment: @Polygnome: It's a bit nuanced. No one explains the fact of being a writer using the word *artist*, but a writer explains the experience of writing as the experience of an artist, simply because, indeed, writing is an art and therefore a writer is an artist. So whether the writer identifies as an artist depends on whether being asked "what are you?" or "what is your experience as a writer?"

Comment: "Science" here also doesn't necessarily refer to the subject being studied, but the "approach" used to study it.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, it's true, but this kind of analysis (as well as the kind from the earlier dilemma of whether "culinary arts" are indeed art) is an easy way to move the discussion from a narrow lexical topic into some epic conversation. Since the question is over word usages, I feel inclined to sidestep questions such as "What is art?" and "What is science?".

Answer (score 21):

The other answers have pointed to the distinction between *art* and *arts* in Modern English, a polysemous word borrowed from Latin via French. **There is a historical dimension to this, which I think is a crucial part of the explanation.**

If you went to [university in medieval Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university), you wouldn't study Linguistics or Economics or anything like that, but instead all of the classical "seven liberal arts" comprising the medieval *trivium* and *quadrivium*: grammar, logic, rhetoric, arithmetic, geometry, music and astronomy. Having studied these, you'd receive a *baccalaureus/magister artium* degree, where it is to be noted that *artium* is the plural genitive of *ars* (to be translated something like "skill"). Since you studied several subjects, it made sense for the designation to be in plural, too. This usage seems to have continued into more modern times, even though modern universities are structured in completely different ways and even though subjects like arithmetic and astronomy are hardly considered liberal arts anymore.

Back in those times, on the other hand, there was no such thing as a "Faculty of Science". (Having a BA or MA in hand, you could go on to study law, medicine or theology, but not "Science".) The notion of (natural) science as a unified enterprise is much more modern, and the first faculties of science were founded relatively late (e.g. 1850 at the [University of Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Copenhagen_Faculty_of_Science), almost 400 years after the foundation of the university itself). At this point, it probably made sense for the degree nomination to be in the singular, as well, though more historical research is needed to establish how all of this unfolded in detail. Incidentally, some languages *do* use the plural with science: Finnish universities, for example, confer the degree of *luonnontieteiden kandidaatti*, literally "bachelor of natural science**s**".

Comment: I think that the historical perspective is valuable. As the usages have changed much over time, earlier decisions might not reflect current norms, but they surely may explain the beginnings of certain traditions. It would be nice if somehow this answer might be expanded to argue why the choice of the singular *science* would have been such a compelling choice even in spite of the likely pressure to preserve the established precedent from the plural *arts*.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer, I really appreciate this angle, and it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: And such plural usage in some languages is not modern either: Fracis Bacon wrote "De dignitate et augmentis scientiarum" where scientiarum is obviously the plural genitive "of sciences".

Comment: I think this is the only truly correct answer. The other answers focus on the true but not insightful fact that either "Science" or "Sciences" ("Art" or "Arts") would be acceptable in modern use. They do not address the origin of the difference in idiomatic use, and thus do not answer the question.

Comment: @epl: I would guess that it's a Bachelor/Master of Science degree because it's generally awarded in just one science (sometimes two, if you do a dual major).  So it's a BS in Chemistry, Physics, or whatever, unlike the historical arts degree.

Comment: @jamesqf But the MA degree is (usually) also awarded in one art: MA in Sociology/Econ/Psyc.

Comment: @jamesqf: So your view is that "of" has the sense "in some particular", rather than of "within"?

Comment: @AIQ: I'm assuming that, as this answer says, "Arts" is a continuance of the traditional practice inherited from medieval times.  The BS/MS degrees came along much later, so were named according to the practice of their time.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot improve upon the other two excellent answers but I'll just give a short answer.

*Arts* refers to the humanities, which is multi-disciplinary.

*Science* is multi-disciplinary as well. For example, both biologists and engineers have a Bachelors of Science. It's just that *art* is usually used to refer to something specific, whereas *science* is already a broad term.

Therefore, we don't use **Bachelor of Art** because *art* is something specific. *Arts* is meant to accomplish the same broad feel as *science* already does. It's not that *science* isn't multidisciplinary, it's that *art* isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the long-standing idiom [The Arts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20arts) from which "Arts" has been taken as the name of that area of study.

Other disciplines lack this herritage and so are plainly named in the singluar.